# New Inserted Row Doesn't displayed in Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am inserting new row in kendo Grid by using PopUp, I am also able to save the Data into Database. But after Insertion of Data on server side when I came back to my View Page at that time I am getting Blank values insserted in my New Row.

my kendo Grid in View is as::

```
<div class="span10">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.ReferenceViewModel>()
    .Name("Reference")
            .TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:20px; " })
                //.TableHtmlAttributes(new { style:"height:30px;"})
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Reference).Width(15);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Width(15);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Value).Width(7);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text(" "); command.Destroy().Text(" "); }).Width(13);
    })
                .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("NewReference"))
    .Navigatable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(200))
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Reference))
        .Create("Reference_Create", "Document")
        .Read("Reference_Read", "Document")
        .Update("Reference_Update", "Document")
        .Destroy("Reference_Destroy", "Document")
    )
        )
    </div>
<button type="button" class="k-button k-grid-Add" id="AddSingleReference"> <span class="k-icon k-add"></span></button><br />
```

and the code on server side is as::

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Reference_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ReferenceViewModel Reference)
        {

                if (Reference != null && ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    string ReferenceName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["models[0].Reference"].ToString();
                    string Description = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["models[0].Description"].ToString();

                    var reference = new CustomerReference { ReferenceName = ReferenceName, Description = Description, CustomerID = 2, CompanyID = 2, ReferenceCode="Ref_Code" };
                    db.CustomerReferences.Add(reference);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }

                return Json(new[] { Reference }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
            }
```

Its inserting new value into database But How can I show these values in Kendo Grid after insertion.
Now after new insertion Kendo Grid is showing Blank spaces.\Please help me on this.

Comment: I have found the answer or another alternative for doing this. 

I have passed (IEnumerable<ReferenceViewModel> models)
then its detected into the Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the Updated object in your response, not the one that is actually sent from the client.

e.g.

```
return Json(new[] { reference }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
```